# Parent-Child Insertion inside TransactionScope cause foreign key constraint error

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, transactionscope

I'm trying to insert data for parent child relationship inside `TransactionScope` and I get `INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint` error. Here is my code:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        discount = discountDataAccess.Insert(discount);
        switch (discount.Type)
        {
            case eDiscountType.PerCustomer:
                InsertDiscountCustomer(discount.Id, idList);
                break;

            case eDiscountType.PerPackage:
                InsertDiscountPackage(discount.Id, idList);
                break;
        }

        scope.Complete();
        return discount;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        scope.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

When `DiscountCustomer` or `DiscountPackage` will be  inserted, `Discount.Id` still is `0` because no data inserted to database until `scope.Complete()` called. So basically I can't save the `DiscountCustomer` or `DiscountPackage` until I commit `Discount` and `Transaction` is not committed until both saved successfully.

Is there any way to insert both parent and child inside `TransactionScope` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out it's not possible with distributed transactions because `TransactionScope` is still in the context of the method and nothing will be inserted till `scope.Complete()` gets called, but it can be done by `SqlTransaction` class, which can be retrieved from `SqlConnection`.

```
try
{
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    discount = discountDataAccess.Insert(discount, transaction);
    switch (discount.Type)
    {
        case eDiscountType.PerCustomer:
            InsertDiscountCustomer(discount.Id, idList, transaction);
            break;

        case eDiscountType.PerPackage:
            InsertDiscountPackage(discount.Id, idList, transaction);
            break;
    }

    transaction.Commit();
    return discount;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (transaction != null)
        transaction.Rollback();

    throw;
}
```

Comment: and how is the `discountDataAccess.Insert(discount, transaction)` handled. Would love to see if it also creates another connection or uses the existing connection

Comment: @Tonto By creating a `SqlTransaction` on an existing connection and using the transaction in `SqlCommand`s.

Comment: using similar with dapper, it still complains of Foreign Key conflicts though `SqlTransaction` is passed to the method and it can only commit it when all is successful

Comment: I have implemented the same functionality with Dapper, it might helps
https://dev.to/moesmp/transaction-middleware-in-aspnet-core-2608

Comment: the app is a legacy .net framework 4.8 app. thanks for the direction